# How to stream local audio to HTTP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, audio, vnc, http

How can I set up a HTTP audio streaming server that I can access on `http://localhost:8080` **without specialized software or configuration on the local side?** (the remote side, which streams the audio, can install any software)

It should be like remote desktop screen sharing, but only audio. For example, `remote --> TeamViewer --> local`, but wihout the TeamViewer/external server in the middle.

The audio that should be streamed is whatever is playing on the remote server (accessed with `ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@domain.com`). The remote server already has VNC set up (video only on port 5900, no audio).

I intend to open `http://localhost:8080` on the local computer as a separate browser tab so I can hear the audio of the remote server while using VNC (audio delay is fine). The extra `-L 8080:localhost:8080` to the `ssh` command does not count as specialized configuration.

Comment: replace "socialized" with "specialized", my phone's autocorrect got me.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the remote server (which will stream the audio) can install any software. It is just local side (which will consume the remote's audio) that should not have specialized software.

Comment: But then replace "server" with client in my comment: same problem

Comment: @MarcusMüller the client should be able to access over HTTP. For example, Firefox/Google Chrome/Internet Explorer/Edge is pre-installed on most OSes and is not "specialized software". Even [VNC has a web client](https://novnc.com/noVNC/vnc.html), so it should be possible with audio too?

Comment: I'd call both VLC and browsers highly specialized software? But yeah, both could probably do. So, up already have your answer, now I'm a bit confused what you're then asking?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I only how to do it conceptually, but not in practice.

Comment: Ahhh now I understand!